# Why is the default delay for the static application switcher pop up set to 0.2s?

Tags: ccsm

At first I thought it was just lag. It's a horrible default setting in my opinion, since when I hold alt+tab, I don't expect to have to wait. As default, it seems to make my experience less smooth.

Comment: why don't you just change it? it's a defualt value anyway like the size of the icons, the size of the windows, the volume being muted whne freshly installed..etc, something like 1.000 it's pretty responsive

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I thought it was just my setup! I've made a Q+A so people can adjust this setting at least: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43875/how-do-i-adjust-the-alt-tab-speed

Comment: Yeah, I realized we can change the default setting, but it makes it slightly more annoying to use and can be misinterpreted as 'lag'. A better default setting would be like 0.1, or something. That small of a difference matters in terms of usability.

Answer (score 1):

When quickly switching between two applications, you don't necessarily want to see a popup. That is what the 0.2s is for.  You can decrease the actual window switch delay by changing the speed from 4 to ~1. This is probably the setting you are looking for - I don't see any reason for delaying the pop-up.