# How to make terminal windows half-transparent in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity, configuration, window-manager, unity-2d, transparency

That's it. I want to have terminal windows to be (half-) transparent in Unity 2d without wasting too much resources.

This question has arisen after an update from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10, after which [I was happy to find, that I can switch from Unity 3d back to Unity 2d](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67204/how-to-restore-change-alttab-behaviour-ram-usage-and-a-few-other-things-after-u).

I have tried to use gconf-editor, but haven't find anything useful there (only a few entries about unity-2d in desktop-->unity-2d, which doesn't seem to be relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the terminal, goto the Menu bar -> **Edit** -> **Profiles**, click on the **Default** profile, then **Edit**, click on the **Background** tab. The bottom half of the window lets you mess with transparency. YMMV

Comment: Thank you. Menu entry was slightly different, but I've got it. I have these settings in Menu button > Profiles > Profile Preferences (and then bottom part of the Background tab).