# installing Ubuntu 64 bit 15.04 on Origin EON 17SLX(machine has windos 8.1 preinstalled)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install ubuntu 64 bit 15.04 on a Origin EON 17SLX
I have disabled fast boot and the secure boot option is disabled in the firmware.
To boot to windows, the EFI boot must be enabled, otherwise the machine does not see its windows boot up section.
I have tried creating a ubuntu boot usb by using  unetbootin-windows-613, when the machine tried to access the usb, a lot of text is printed scrolling like mad, eventually the machine lock up showing some form of collapsed image.

I am not sure what the issue is, according to all of the on line help that I have read disabling fast boot and secure boot and booting from an EFI boot usb stick should work.  I have also tried uvunto 14.04 with the same results.  Centos 7 managed to draw 8 tux's at the top of the display before dying.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

I would love to know how to get some sort of diangostic out it.

The machine has a NVIA GTX 980m as a graphics card, 2x 120GB Samsung 850 Evo mSata drives and two 1TB Samsung 850 pro drives.  The raid option is disabled.

Comment: Triedit with secure boot enabled, no luck.  Tried it with efi boot disabled, secure boot disabled, disabled the raid support on the boot.  Result fried the windows boot loader and failed to even load ubunto in memoery.

Is there any way of getting some logging out of the ubuntu installer ?

Comment: Had issues with ubuntu 15.04, machine locks up, but noticed a chirp sound from it, noticed that the screen is totally blank.  Tried mint 17.02, after another blank screen tried booting in compatabiliy mode.  Lots of printed text and stops with comments about SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP.DSM Argument #4 mistmatched Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] 2-14-24/nsarguments-95 failed to evaluate _DSM.  I suspect the problem is that the boot is fine(the ubuntu boot noise)  I suspect that support for the video card is missing from the boot CD, the video driver is NVDIA GTX 980m which is a new video card.

Comment: Tried again with a monitor connected to the external video port of the graphics card SUCCESS I see an ubuntu prompt.  I need to install the nvdia graphics card Ctrl Atl F1,  a login prompt , all I need to do is login as root install the nvia gaphics driver, small problem DAMMED machine is asking for a password, does anybody known what it is?

Answer (score 0):

SORTED, got it installed.
After reading all of the profits of doom which stated that getting Linux on an windos 8.1 was going to be hard because of Boot issues anbd efit file systems, the problem turned out to be the graphics card. Ubuntu 15.04 ships with a support driver which does not support the GSX 980M card.
To boot the machine must be boot with the 'nomodeset' option set. Set the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/67204...4-installation and search for nomodeset. This will enable you load the boot the machine in ubuntu and install a base operating system. You then need to load the drivers for the GSX 980M card, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bi...erHowto/Nvidia.

Once this is done, you can have a dule boot machine. Currently I can turn my machine on and it will boot in to grub which offers me a choice of either windows or Linux.

So I now have an choice of os's