# Is there any way to go to the old switcher behavior?

Tags: 11.10, application-switcher

The new switcher in 11.10 *looks* really great, but I feel like it is a loss in productivity to me.  I have multiple instances of several applications open at once (especially browsers) many times and I like to be able to switch quickly between the all with one hand.  Now I have to either alt-tab and pause for a long time for the grouped windows to automatically expand, or I have to use my other hand to press down while holding alt to expand the windows.

Is there a way to go back to selectively go back to the old behavior where each process gets its own separate entry in the switcher where things are not grouped together?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simpler ALT-TAB in Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45821/simpler-alt-tab-in-unity)

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/43875/how-do-i-adjust-the-alt-tab-speed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I revert Alt-tab behavior changed in 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/how-do-i-revert-alt-tab-behavior-changed-in-11-10)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the key above tab) does the same as hitting down and only requires one hand.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between different applications. You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the key above Tab) to switch between the different instances in an application.

Comment: And these can be mix and matched - alt-tab to get to the application you're after, then hit ` without releasing alt to get to the window you're after.  I find it can be faster than going through all the windows :).

Comment: Thanks - that works much better.  I'll have to get used to switching between the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Unity Alt-Tab switching in Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM), then activate any other window switching plugin in the Window Management section.

Answer (score -1):

you can always use <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> which is all of the windows in a circle

Comment: I'm not familiar with this - how do I enable this?

Comment: you can go into the advanced compiz settings and scroll down to window management then you click ring switcher and enable it

Comment: This answer lacks info. The original poster should add more info about the functionality of this application switcher.