# Alt-tab application switchers don't show miniatures

Tags: 11.10, application-switcher

I cannot change the behavior of Alt-tab. It only shows icons, not miniatures. I can change key-bindings in Compiz config, but not the behavior. Also, Ring Switcher, Shift switcher etc. does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45821/simpler-alt-tab-in-unity) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43875/how-do-i-adjust-the-alt-tab-speed).

In the Static Application Switcher CCSM settings, there is an option to show/hide icon and to see the miniature screen.