# How can I remove the Alt+Tab timeout?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

In Oneiric there's a timeout when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> before the icons show. How can I remove that timeout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I adjust the alt-tab speed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43875/how-do-i-adjust-the-alt-tab-speed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/888636/+attachment/2624706/+files/0001-Add-alt_tab_delay-option-to-configure-alt-tab-delay.patch) suggested in a [launchpad discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/888636) about this issue, and I've compiled it. Now I can configure the timeout (it's the "Delay before showing switcher" option at the top). I've uploaded the compiled deb files (for Oneiric 64 bit) [on 4shared](http://www.4shared.com/file/IgPHfkgs/alt_tab_delay.html) and [in a torrent](http://www.seedpeer.me/details/4022767/alt-tab-delay.html), if anyone wants it.

[image]

Comment: Torrent doesn't appear to be up any more. Can you point me to some resources that describe how to compile and apply the patch as you did?

Comment: I haven't turned on my computer in the last couple of days, that's all. Just don't delete the torrent and you'll download it eventually. Doesn't the 4shared link work?

Answer (score 1):

If http://iloveubuntu.net/alttab-ing-gets-automatic-preview-oneiric-ocelot is right, then `alt_tab_timeout` is not configurable right now. That's stupid, i know.

Comment: Can it be edited manually with gconf?

Comment: Afaik, you configure Unity using either `CompizConfig Settings Manager` or `dconf-editor`, and there is no option for alt+tab timeout (http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/62903#62903). Maybe file a bug? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/FilingBugs

Comment: I've managed to make it configurable finally, I've posted  it as an answer, and I'm going to select it as the right answer, I hope it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround :> 
- hold Alt and push Tab until You reach the application You want to select
- still holding the Alt push the down arrow key 
It will show You the child windows of your selected application immediately.