# Can I shorten the timing in the Alt+Tab dialog?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, window-management

I like the new <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dialog in Oneiric, but when I stop on an application it takes too long to break into the window-select mode. It seems like it takes a second or even more, and I'd like it to be around a quarter of that time.

Can I change this behavior and shorten the time it takes to break into windows?

I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66666/how-can-i-remove-the-alttab-timeout), but it seems to be asking about the initial dialog display, not the secondary one.

Comment: Do you have package compizconfig-settings-manager installed? (Command: ccsm) This may have a setting in the plugin that controls alt-tab (something window switcher).

Comment: @JoeP I do have CCSM installed, and I've looked at the settings, but can't find anything useful. All the settings that pertain to the new switcher seem to be under the "Unity" section, and there's essentially only options to change the key bindings. The other switchers in the Window Management section all disable the new switcher and enable the older one.

Comment: Just because I'm wondering - what do you use the window switcher mode for?  At least on my system to change between windows you would either need to alt-tab to the desired application, hit down and then use the arrow keys to switch between windows or you have to go to the applications and use alt-` to switch between windows anyways.  Do you just want to glance at what windows are open for a certain applications without necessarily a desire to switch to a particular one?

Comment: @Dason If I tab to an application with multiple windows and wait, I can Alt+Tab through them, which will eventually go to the next application. That's one reason. The other is that I think pressing Alt+` to break up the windows is bad UI design. The command Alt+` switches between windows, so when I'm hovering on an application and press it, I expect it to switch windows, but instead it breaks them up and selects the first one. That's like pressing Alt+Tab to bring up the switcher, but not actually switching to the next application and just selecting the current application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you're on the application of interest you could use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows in that application.

Comment: This is true, and it does work instantly. I was hoping to shorten the waiting period, without further interaction, but I might have to settle for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that has already been [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/836023). It will probably be fixed in the near future.

Comment: This bug seems to only be about the initial appearance of the Alt-Tab switcher, whereas I'm concerned about the delay that happens when one has already activated the switcher, and pauses on an application with multiple windows open.

Comment: I misunderstood the "it takes too long to break into the window-select mode". I tried both my ubuntu machines and it works fine on mine. Sorry I couldn't help more. Updates is the only other thing I can think of...

Comment: @root45  Yeah, I have the same problem, so I can confirm that it exists on my system too.