# How to make alt-tab switch quickly?

Tags: 10.04, application-switcher

I've just used recently Debian and I'm using Windows 7, and one thing that really gets on my nerves is the alt-tab feature: to access the second program it's easy: *alt-tab switches instantaneously from the current window to the next one*. But if I want to access quickly to the third program I have to wait something like 1/2 second, and that's really annoying, because as a developper, I'm always switching between my shell, Firefox, and the third one, Firebug Window.

Is there something I could do to make alt-switching fast when accessing *other windows than the next*? I don't know, maybe remove an effect (I'm currently with the option "visual effects : normal").

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this delay; When I press <Alt>+<Tab>, <Tab> the third window is brought into focus immediately. Can you clarify why you have to wait a half-second before switching to the third window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might be waiting for the application switcher to appear on screen before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again. You don't have to do this; pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> before the application switcher appears will still bring the third window into focus.

If you'd like to reduce the 0.2-second delay before the application switcher is displayed, see [How do I adjust the alt-tab speed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/43875/1859).

Comment: Thank you I've googled but didn't find this link. It worked `\o/` Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In my PC, it works if I just keep pressed the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, while press several times the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key