# How to change Alt+Tab application switcher in 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I adjust the alt-tab speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43875/how-do-i-adjust-the-alt-tab-speed)

Default alt+tab application switcher is slow. Previously faster ones could be used through CCSM but the options seem to be gone. Any way to re-enable them?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/43876/92745), if your problem isn't fixed, you can try changing the keyboard shortcut of alt + tab to another program to handle.

Comment: Right, in previous versions of Ubuntu that's how I did it, but in 12.10 those options are gone.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/233344/32580